# Why might the “fatal error C1001” error occur intermittently when using openmp?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, openmp

My code works well without #openmp
but I got this error when I added #openmp compiler

> 1>c:\users\hdd amd ali\documents\v studio 10 projects\visual studio 2010\projects\escaledesvols2 - copy\escaledesvols2\djikstra.cpp(116): fatal error C1001: An internal error occurred in the compiler.
>   1> (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\wvm\mdmiscw.c', ligne 1098)

note:
i use many different libraries (like #boost)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h> // for unmanaged piece of code
#include <vcclr.h>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply report it.

In terms of workarounds, it is likely related to memory/resource consumption. Usual tricks to lower consumption are

- disable debug information
- split up compilation units to smaller size (this might be key here: "I'm using many libraries" should not be an issue unless you're including all the headers in a single translation unit
- try to reduce template instantiations

Alternatively

- reduce system load (close other programs, such as your Stackoverflow browser that might tatke valuable resources :))

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue recently; I was compiling with visual studio 2015. I tried it with visual studio 2017 and I still got the internal compiler error. Then I tried it with visual studio 2013 and it told me that I can't have a "return" statement inside an openMP section. when I removed the return from VS 2013 and VS 2105 the compiler was able to successfully compile. So, it make sense to try it with VS 2013 and it will give you a better error description. You could also be having return statements inside openMP sections and that could be the reason for c1001 error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a return function from the OpenMP loop. Removing a "return" line solved the problem.